# Zend Form - getElement by type

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to get the element of the Zend form by type? Specifically, I want to be able to change the submit label text, but don't want to refer to it by id, and want to get it based on the type="submit".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all the elements and check their type.

```
$submits = array();
foreach ($form->getElements() as $element) {
  if ($element->getType() == 'submit') $submits[] = $element;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
$form = new Zend_Form(array(
      'elements' => array(
            'submit' => array(
               'type' => 'submit',
            ),
      )));

$form->getElement('submit')->setLabel('Ok!');
```

**EDIT** *Addition to who put a minus :)*

Class `Zend_Form` doesnt has method like `getElementsByType`. In this specify case (`type="submit"`) I suggested to get submit by name (`submit`) ( or do you frequently work with forms with 2,3,4... submit inputs inside ?).